# Slicing an array by page

Tags: php

```
function date_compare($a, $b)
    {
        $t1 = strtotime($a['lastEdit']);
        $t2 = strtotime($b['lastEdit']);
        return $t1 - $t2;
    }    
    usort($container, 'date_compare');

    $totalPages = floor($count/12);

    $start = $page * 12 - 11;
    $end = $page * 12;

    $container = array_reverse($container);
    $container = array_slice($container, $start, $end);


    return $container;
```

My `start` doesn't seem to affect the `slice` method. When I'm on page 2 for example, (start: 13 and end: 24), I still get a `array(24)` returned. What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd parameter to `array_slice` is not actually "end", but rather "length" -- see the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

So change

```
$end = $page * 12;
```

to

```
$len = $page * 12 - $start
```

and

```
$container = array_slice($container, $start, $end);
```

to

```
$container = array_slice($container, $start, $len);
```

Note `$len` might be off by one if you expected `$end` to not be inclusive.

**Edit:**
Actually, it looks like you could just specify the length parameter as 11 as it looks fixed.

Answer (score 0):

From [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

> **length**
>
> If length is given and is positive, then the sequence will have
>   up to that many elements in it. If the array is shorter than the
>   length, then only the available array elements will be present. If
>   length is given and is negative then the sequence will stop that many
>   elements from the end of the array. If it is omitted, then the
>   sequence will have everything from offset up until the end of the
>   array.

So perhaps you should give `$end - $start` instead of plain `$end`?